# How to point ALL deployed SSRS reports to different shared datasource on report server?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, power-bi-report-server

I have more than a hundred deployed reports on a report server that basically using same shared datasource.
Now I need to repoint all of them to a different datasource.

So I am manually going through each report on a report server and pointing it to a different shared datasource.

Is any way to do that for all reports at once?

[image]

Comment: Surely the point of a shared datasource is that you just update the datasource itself?

Comment: I am not sure whether I'm using best practices, but when I deploy a report to a server, I point it to a shared datasource in a folder "Datasources". So yes, we added reporting database, so  I need to repoint it to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer but I think it points you in a direction that might get you unlocked:

I would check into the ReportServer database.  I think there appear to be 2 relevant tables.  [DataSource]
and

```
SELECT SDS.name AS SharedDsName 
       ,SDS.[Path] 
       ,CONVERT(xml, CONVERT(varbinary(max), content)) AS DEF 
 FROM dbo.[Catalog] AS SDS 
 WHERE SDS.Type = 5
```

I found a great query that hints at this here:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-connection-strings-of-1a9a9adc

That query is:

```
-- List connection strings of all SSRS Shared Datasources 
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES  -- XML namespace def must be the first in with clause. 
    (DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2006/03/reportdatasource' 
            ,'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner' 
     AS rd) 
,SDS AS 
    (SELECT SDS.name AS SharedDsName 
           ,SDS.[Path] 
           ,CONVERT(xml, CONVERT(varbinary(max), content)) AS DEF 
     FROM dbo.[Catalog] AS SDS 
     WHERE SDS.Type = 5)     -- 5 = Shared Datasource 
 
SELECT CON.[Path] 
      ,CON.SharedDsName 
      ,CON.ConnString 
FROM 
    (SELECT SDS.[Path] 
           ,SDS.SharedDsName 
           ,DSN.value('ConnectString[1]', 'varchar(150)') AS ConnString 
     FROM SDS 
          CROSS APPLY  
          SDS.DEF.nodes('/DataSourceDefinition') AS R(DSN) 
     ) AS CON 
-- Optional filter: 
-- WHERE CON.ConnString LIKE '%Initial Catalog%=%TFS%' 
ORDER BY CON.[Path] 
        ,CON.SharedDsName;
```